# How can I get a Select elements Options to "right-width" but leave the width of the Select itself unchanged?

Tags: css, html-select

This CSS can be used to alter the width of a Select when it is in use:

```
select:focus {width:300px;}
```

...but I want just the Options (the drop down bit) to increase in width, not the Select element itself (as it appears prior to dropping down the options).

IOW, considering a Select Option of "Fiver was a Rabbit, but unlike Peter and Roger" as an option in the Select, rather than being displayed like this when dropped down:

```
| Select  Element when "at rest" |
Fiver was a Rabbit, but unlike Pe
```

(Option truncated)

...or this:

```
| Select  Element when "at rest"              |
Fiver was a Rabbit, but unlike Peter and Roger|
```

(Select Element taking up too much real estate and elbowing elements to its right out of the way)

...I want it to be like this:

```
| Select  Element when "at rest" |
Fiver was a Rabbit, but unlike Peter and Roger|
```

(Select remains the same width, but the Options "right-width" to be just wide enough to show all the text, but no wider).

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Also an image demonstrating desired behavior: http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/30828/36618

Comment: Exactly; genau; exactamundo

Comment: And a really old near duplicate: stackoverflow.com/q/294040/2908724

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a custom styled wrapper?

HTML:

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
        <option>First option</option>
        <option>Second really really really long option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.select-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;

    &::after {
        content: "\2193";
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
        top: 0;
    }

    select {
        background: transparent;
        border: 0;
        padding: 3px;
    }
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vqq2a68/) for an example. It's not pretty, but you can get the idea.

---

**Update:** Based on B. Clay Shannon's comment, see this [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4vqq2a68/2/), without the surrounding div.

Comment: Very cool, but I prefer it without the div, and moving the class to the Select itself as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/4vqq2a68/1/

Comment: true, this is much cleaner!